# Редактирование готового pdf файла. PHP/Python

Tags: python, php, парсер, pdf

Всем привет. Появилась нужда редактировать PDF файл, при этом мне не приходит уже готовый pdf файл. В нём надо найти определённую строчку, проверить, соответствует ли она тому, что я ожидаю, и если нет - изменить, при этом шаблон меняться не должен, и файл визуально должен оставить свою векторность.

Пока что дошел только до напяливания вотермарки на этот пдф, но решение временное. Чем дольше ищу - тем больше отчаиваюсь, потому что гугл весь говорит, что дело это гиблое.

fpdf и fpdi так же есть и используется, но такого функционала в нём не нашел.

Для уточнения вставлю скриншот, чтобы был пример, что надо менять.
[image: Пример старницы из документа]

То, что мне надо сделать - это, например, найти в pdf файле, который может быть на 100 страниц - строку +44(0)20 8963 0336, проверить, подходит ли она под мои условия, и, если нет, изменить её, чтобы после этого в pdf документе она стала другой. После чего этот документ отправится к пользователю.

P.S. Была идея написать скрипт на Питоне, но там тоже не нашел, хотя и искал не так хорошо, ибо с питоном не так сильно дружу.

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework: https://github.com/zf1/zend-pdf

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Pdf.php';

$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load('blank.pdf');
$page = $pdf->pages[0];
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);
$page->setFont($font, 12);
$page->drawText('Hello world!', 72, 720);
$pdf->save('zend.pdf');
```

Comment: Показанный вами код добавляет новую строчку, а найти и изменить существующую как?